# Do inbound links pass link juice up the url hierarchy?

Tags: seo, url, pagerank, ranking, url-slug

Our site is very regional, so we focus all of our seo efforts on each of these region landing pages.

**For Example:** `domain.com/toys/us/ca/san-francisco`

We added an informational page (ex. reviews) and give it a url like this: `domain.com/toys/us/ca/san-francisco/reviews`

Will inbound links to `domain.com/toys/.../reviews` provide any link juice value to it's hierarchical parent page: `domain.com/toys/us/ca/san-francisco`?

Comment: Not directly. But assuming /reviews links to /san-francisco it will benefit from the /reviews page being stronger thus its links being stronger as well.

Comment: If it helps, think of links like the plumbing in your house- water cannot flow if there is no pipe (link) from one place to another. Your reviews page cannot pass any benefit another page without your linking to it.